# How to format a date string like '2018-08-31'

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I've got a date-string like '2018-08-31' from tt_content and want to convert it like this: '31 August 2018' - how do I get this to work?

I've tried this:

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    wrap = |
    data.field = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date  // field in tt_content, is '2018-08-31'
    strftime = %e %B %Y
}
```

But this puts out the **current date** (in the desired format). Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Please do not modify your question to show the solution. That invalidates the question, and confuses readers. If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution: With `strtotime = 1` the string will be converted into a timestamp and then `strftime` will work as expected:

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    wrap = |
    field = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date  // field in tt_content, is '2018-08-31'
    strtotime = 1
    strftime = %e %B %Y
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    wrap = |
    field = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date
    strftime = %e %B %Y
}
```

`data.field = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date` will set the content of `tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date` as the value for `data`, which will result in nothing. `field` directly in the `TEXT` object will set the content of `tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date` as the value of the `TEXT` object, which will then be passed through `strftime`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But this didn't work either - now the result is '1 January 1970' (format is right, but the date not).

Comment: How is this used exactly? Does it work with other fields (without the strftime)? Try uid, to check if you really have the correct content element.

Comment: The Typoscript snippet is part of a larger Typoscript to get teasers out of a collection of pages. Within each teaser, a date is displayed. As you can see in the field name, the date line comes from the 'date' field of the mask extension. If I don't use strftime, the date of the corresponding field in tt_content is output as it is (e.g. '2018-08-31', which is correct - only the output format is not what I want it to be).

Comment: strftime requires a timestamp, not a date string. There is no way with pure TypoScript to convert a string like `2018-08-31` to a timestamp. You'd need a userfunc for that.

Comment: I just found a solution: with `strtotime = 1` the string will be converted into a timestamp and then strftime works as it should.

Comment: I did not know this function was in TypoScript. Glad it works now.